# React-Native Table Cell alignment Row

Tags: react-native

I want to style each Cell of my Table differently depending on the Data which I get. If I use a Cell element the Element always create a Line Break.

How can I avoid this and render it in the row direction?

I use react-native-table-component,react-native-paginated-listview

```
     <PaginatedListView
                           style={{ marginBottom:30}}
                           renderRow={(data,i) =>
                             {
                               this._cellBack = !this._cellBack;
                               return(
                                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => this._onPressButton(e,data)}>
                                   <View style={styles.button}>
                                     <Cell key="1" data="1" height={28} style={[styles.tableCell, this._cellBack && {backgroundColor: '#DFF5F2'}]}  textStyle={styles.tableCellText} widthArr={this._widthArr} myProp="10"/>
                                     <Cell key="2" data="2" height={28} style={[styles.tableCell, this._cellBack && {backgroundColor: '#DFF5F2'}]}  textStyle={styles.tableCellText} widthArr={this._widthArr} myProp="10"/>
                                   </View>
                                 </TouchableOpacity>
                               );
                             }
                           }
                           itemsPerPage={this._LOADLIMIT}
                           onFetch={::this.onFetch}
                           autoFetch={false}/>
```

Comment: changing the style may be help you of you view style={{flexDireaction:'row'}}

Comment: Thank you 
I had to set the View direction to Row

Comment: please a thum up for my answer , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the style may be help you of you view `style={{flexDireaction:'row'}}`